# Оконная функция row_number не работает с результатом regexp_matches

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица PostgreSql (версия 16) с футбольной статистикой следующей структуры:

team_id smallint -- код команды

rez text -- результаты команды за сезон, собранные в 1 строку.

rez содержит информацию к примеру "XXDXDXXXXXXXXXXDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDDXXDXXX",
где D - ничья, X - победа или поражение.

Стоит задача выбрать все серии (группы, в которых X встречается подряд 10 и более раз). У команды может быть несколько серий, в том числе одинаковой длины.

С помощью запроса

```
select team_id, 
    rez, 
    regexp_matches(rez, '([X]{10,})(.?){1,1}', 'g') as pattern 
from group_ 
order by team_id
```

мне удалось выделить команды с сериями, при этом количество строк для команды соответствует количеству серий.

Дальше возникла задача пронумеровать серии для команды по порядку возникновения. Пробую использовать оконную функцию row_number()

```
select team_id, 
    rez, 
    regexp_matches(rez, '([X]{10,})(.?){1,1}', 'g') as pattern, 
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY team_id ORDER BY team_id) AS r__n
from group_ 
order by team_id
```

Вот результат запроса, но все номера строк равны 1. При этом у команды с кодом 3834 выделены 2 серии.

```
"team_id","rez","pattern","r__n"
2152,"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDDDXXXXXDXDXXXXDDDDXDDX","{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,D}","1"
3834,"XXDXDXXXXXXXXXXDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDDXXDXXX","{XXXXXXXXXX,D}","1"
3834,"XXDXDXXXXXXXXXXDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDDXXDXXX","{XXXXXXXXXXXXXX,D}","1"
4848,"XXXXDXXXXXXXXXXDDDXXDDXXXDXXXXXXDDXXXX","{XXXXXXXXXX,D}","1"
```

Подскажите, как можно исправить запрос для корректной нумерации строк.

Дополнение.
При использовании временной таблицы все работает как ожидалось.

```
WITH all_team AS ( 
  select team_id, rez, 
     regexp_matches(rez, '([X]{10,})(.?){1,1}', 'g') as pattern 
  from group_ 
) 
select all_team.*, 
   row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY team_id ORDER BY team_id) AS r__n
from all_team
ORDER BY team_id
```

Comment: *Вот результат запроса, но все номера строк равны 1.* Я Вам не верю. `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY team_id ORDER BY team_id)` не может вернуть одинаковые результаты для разных записей с равным `team_id`. См. [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/RBqU5syP

Comment: В исходной таблице коды команд не повторяются. 

Поэтому 

INSERT INTO group_1 VALUES (2152,'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDDDXXXXXDXDXXXXDDDDXDDX'), (3834,'XXDXDXXXXXXXXXXDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXDDXXDXXX'), (4848,'XXXXDXXXXXXXXXXDDDXXDDXXXDXXXXXXDDXXXX');

Comment: Я взял ровно то, что показано. Текст показанного запроса, и исходная таблица, построенная из якобы полученного результата оставлением только исходных полей. И сделал это специально. Если ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО изучить fiddle, то в голову должна прийти простая мысль. Количество regexp_matches для значения - более чем одна штука.

Comment: Можете попробовать ``from group_ cross join regexp_matches(rez, '([X]{10,})(.?){1,1}', 'g') as pattern`` вместо ``select *, regexp_matches(rez, '([X]{10,})(.?){1,1}', 'g') as pattern``. Однако, если совпадения с шаблоном нет, эта строка не будет включена в выходной результат (https://dbfiddle.uk/6K4PvSR8), как и в других вариантах.  Ваш вариант с CTE вполне рабочий, временной таблицы там нет.